# While parsing pdf with iText7 chars move on fixed interval (with Freeset font)

Tags: java, java-8, itext7

I'm trying to parse pdf that I have created with iText. In document I have two paragraphs:

- "Имя" - ("name" from Russian) - font: Helvetica, size: 20.
- "Фамилия" - ("surname" from Russian) - font: Freeset (I downloaded it [here](http://allfont.ru/download/freeset/)), size: 10.

When I finish parsing I get "Имя" properly encoded and "Ôàìèëèÿ" instead of "Фамилия". It is Unicode characters for "Фамилия" but moved 848 chars (10-based) left. (I mean that, for instance, instead of "Ф" (0x0424 in UTF-8) I get "Ô" (0x00d4) and difference between them is 848 (or 350 in hex))

I use [this](https://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/content-extraction-and-redaction/clone-parsing-pdfs) example to get text from pdf (but instead of filtering by font, I filter by equality to one of the Strings in the set ("Имя", "Фамилия")

I know that we are [advised](https://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-use-cyrillic-characters-pdf) to store non-English charactes as sequence of Unicode symbols, but I'm creating pdf on the fly from incoming data so I can't manually retype it as separate Unicode symbols (if you know how to do it on the fly, please provide your approach).

Any ideas why this movement of character happen and how to avoid it are welcomed. Thank you in advance.

[Here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ZihdBx0bDZstb-xVSF5ysXcfHWZ8Gj4d) is the file I worked with.

**Edit**

I tried opening file in Acrobat Pro and everything is fine there. Acrobat also shows that all three fonts I've put in pdf are still in the document.

Here is the code I used to create pdf I'm processing:

```
private static void create() throws IOException {
    PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(srcPdf), new PdfWriter(targetPdf));
    PdfCanvas pdfCanvas = new PdfCanvas(pdf.getFirstPage());
    PdfFont freeset = getPdfFont(freesetPath);
    PdfFont helvetica = getPdfFont(helveticaPath);
    PdfFont circe = getPdfFont(circePath);
    pdfCanvas.beginText()
            .setFontAndSize(helvetica, 15)
            .setColor(Color.RED, true)
            .moveText(50, 300)
            .showText("Имя")
            .setFontAndSize(freeset, 10)
            .setColor(Color.GREEN, true)
            .moveText(0, -30)
            .showText("Фамилия")
            .setFontAndSize(circe, 20)
            .setColor(Color.BLUE, true)
            .moveText(0, -30)
            .showText("Должность")
            .endText();

    pdf.close();
}

private static PdfFont getPdfFont(String path) throws IOException {
    InputStream fontInputStream = new FileInputStream(path);
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
    int a;
    while((a = fontInputStream.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) != -1) {
        baos.write(buffer, 0, a);
    }
    baos.flush();
    return PdfFontFactory.createFont(baos.toByteArray(),
            PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H, true);
}
```

Comment: Please share the PDF in question.

Comment: are you sure you have `UTF-8` when reading those strings?

Comment: @mkl added link to the question. There is also other text but the problem is with text "Фамилия" in light green.

Comment: @Eugene Yes, because text in different font than Freeset (I tried at least two) is read properly.

Comment: @AndreySerebryanskiy very interesting, thx for the update

Comment: First of all, have you ever tried copying&pasting the text in question from a pdf viewer? I'm currently only on a smart phone but the pdf viewers on it all show the same behaviour you describe for iText. So it looks like your PDF is broken. You say you crested it with iText? Can you share the code you did that with? This appears to be an issue of iText while generating the PDF.

Comment: @mkl Yes, I tried to open it with Acrobat and all text is shown properly. Added creation code to the post.

Comment: *"I tried to open it with Acrobat and all text is shown properly"* - yes, it *looks* proper. But have you copied&pasted the text from there? *"Added creation code to the post."* - I'm looking into that.

Comment: @mkl Hm.. Yes, you are right, I didn't get it first time. It does produce "Ôàìèëèÿ" when I copy from Acrobat. Do you know, why is it happening?

Answer (score 1):

iText 7 appears to have an issue with embedding the font in question. I don't know whether it's a bug in the font or in iText, though.

---

The "FreeSet" font is indeed embedded in the OP's sample document with a wrong **ToUnicode** map

```
...
6 beginbfrange
<009e> <009e> <00d4> <00aa> <00aa> <00e0> <00b2> <00b2> <00e8> <00b5> <00b5> <00eb> <00b6> <00b6> <00ec> <00c9> <00c9> <00ff> endbfrange
...
```

which maps the glyphs used for "Фамилия" to 00d4, 00e0, 00e8, 00eb, 00ec, and 00ff.

This in turn explains why both iText and Adobe Reader extract unexpected text.

The issue can be reproduced like this:

```
PdfFont arial = PdfFontFactory.createFont(BYTES_OF_ARIAL_FONT, PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H, true);
PdfFont freeSet = PdfFontFactory.createFont(BYTES_OF_FREESET_FONT, PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H, true);

try (   OutputStream result = new FileOutputStream("cyrillicTextFreeSet.pdf");
        PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(result);
        PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(writer);
        Document doc = new Document(pdfDocument)    ) {
    doc.add(new Paragraph("Фамилия").setFont(arial));
    doc.add(new Paragraph("Фамилия").setFont(freeSet));
}
```

*([CreateCyrillicText](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext7/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext7/content/CreateCyrillicText.java#L50) test `testCreateTextWithFreeSet`)*

The result looks ok:

[image: screenshot]

When extracting / copying&pasting, though:

The embedded Arial subset has a proper **ToUnicode** map, the text in Arial is extracted as "Фамилия".

The embedded FreeSet subset has an incorrect **ToUnicode** map, the text in FreeSet is extracted as "Ôàìèëèÿ".

*(Tested with the current iText 7.1.1-SNAPSHOT)*

Apparently iText 7 does understand the FreeSet font program well enough to select the needed subset and reference the correct glyphs from the content but it has problems building an appropriate **ToUnicode** map. This is not a general problem, though, as the parallel test with Arial shows.

Comment: Thank you. I found another issue, it could be connected. When I looked in the PdfStream by `page.getFirstContentStream()` and found symbols for "Имя" (I got `<01a101c501d8>Tj`), I noticed that they are also shifted (but on 631 10-based).  For freeset shift here is 902, for Circe Light - 705. May be you know the logic of this (and how to predict the shift)? If so, I could solve my problem with PdfStreams.